# How can i draw something in C#

Tags: c#

i'm looking for a way to draw something (like a racing map) in C# as i do in for example paint . then pass information to a toy car to follow it. I don't need you to write a code, i just need a suggestion of the way to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=drawing%20graphics%20in%20c%23

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=moving%20sprites%20in%20c%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) might be something for you. It's a game engine with a free license, and you can program in C#.